# Jquery countdown counter not working properly

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, jquery-countdown

Am creating a coming soon website

```
<div class="countdown styled"></div>
```

From this div, I need a countdown timer. So I used the default countdown timer from jquery.countdown.js.

UI coming correctly and shows seconds at 0 only.

What do I have to do to run a counter?

Am getting Js code at jquery.countdown.js file

```
(function() {

  (function($) {
    $.countdown = function(el, options) {
      var getDateData,
        _this = this;
      this.el = el;
      this.$el = $(el);
      this.$el.data("countdown", this);
      this.init = function() {
        _this.options = $.extend({}, $.countdown.defaultOptions, options);
        if (_this.options.refresh) {
          _this.interval = setInterval(function() {
            return _this.render();
          }, _this.options.refresh);
        }
        _this.render();
        return _this;
      };
      getDateData = function(endDate) {
        var dateData, diff;
        endDate = Date.parse($.isPlainObject(_this.options.date) ? _this.options.date : new Date(_this.options.date));
        diff = (endDate - Date.parse(new Date)) / 1000;
        if (diff <= 0) {
          diff = 0;
          if (_this.interval) {
            _this.stop();
          }
          _this.options.onEnd.apply(_this);
        }
        dateData = {
          years: 0,
          days: 10,
          hours: 10,
          min: 20,
          sec: 14,
          millisec: 10
        };
    
    $.countdown.defaultOptions = {
      date: "Dec 25, 2021 15:03:25",
      refresh: 1000,
      onEnd: $.noop,
      render: function(date) {
        return $(this.el).html("" + date.years + " years, " + date.days + " days, " + (this.leadingZeros(date.hours)) + " hours, " + (this.leadingZeros(date.min)) + " min and " + (this.leadingZeros(date.sec)) + " sec");
      }
    };
    $.fn.countdown = function(options) {
      return $.each(this, function(i, el) {
        var $el;
        $el = $(el);
        if (!$el.data('countdown')) {
          return $el.data('countdown', new $.countdown(el, options));
        }
      });
    };
    return void 0;
  })(jQuery);

}).call(this);
```

But counter not running . Only UI coming . Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you create a https://jsfiddle.net/ with your code?

Comment: `jquery.countdown.js` does not seem to work, and a search just turns up a list of countdown timers, it isn't clear which one you're using. Edit your question, add a link and info about what plugin you're using.